# SSL Proxy for minisites with custom domain

Tags: ssl, https, proxy, dns

I have the following task:

I have minisites for my customers (site1.example.com, site2.example.com, etc'..)

The end customer will create a CNAME record, something like video.customer.com pointing to my proxy server (video.customer.com -> SSL Proxy -> site1.example.com)

I would like to generate and manage the SSL Certificate for this CNAME Record (video.customer.com or a wildcard cert) using Let'sEncrypt.

I need something like a proxy server which will:

1. Identify from which domain the request is coming (video.customer.com).
2. Apply the certificate I've generated with certbot (Let'sEncrypt)
3. Forward the traffic to the minisite (site1.example.com)
4. Renew the certificate when needed

The idea is to do everything automatically except the update of the CNAME record in the customer's domain.

This is the expected workflow:

1. The customer will tell me the domain (video.customer.com)
2. I will generate the minisite
3. I will generate the SSL Cert
4. I will tell the customer to create the CNAME record pointing to the Proxy/minisite.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Dan.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do with NGINX and proxy_pass command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).